# Python: symbolic use of hyp2f1 with sympy

Tags: python, function, sympy, mpmath

In Python, I want to use the hypergeometric function hyp2f1 while keeping at least one symbolic argument. However, there is a TypeError

> cannot create mpf from d

where d is the (last) argument of the hypergeometric function.

Someone asked a similar question

[sympy and mpmath give "TypeError: cannot create mpf" when using the erf() function within solveset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759214/sympy-and-mpmath-give-typeerror-cannot-create-mpf-when-using-the-erf-functi)

after encountering the same problem with the error function erf.
The proposed solution was to use the mpmath library instead of the sympy library, but mpmath cannot be used while keeping arguments symbolic.

I also tried to import mpmath and sympy together as proposed in the sympy documentation:

```py
from sympy.mpmath import *
```

https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/modules/mpmath/functions/hypergeometric.html#common-hypergeometric-series

But this is not accepted, as the output is:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `sympy.mpmath'

My code is

```py
from sympy import *

d = Symbol('d')

hyp2f1(1,1,1,d)
```

I hoped to get [a simplification to 1/(1-d)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hypergeometric2F1%5B1,1,1,d%5D) or at least hoped that Python can 'store' hyp2f1(1,1,1,d) for symbolic manipulations.

I get an error

> TypeError: cannot create mpf from d

The bottom line is, with sympy imported, Python cannot use hyp2f1 with symbolic arguments.

Comment: You linked to a 0.7.6 documentation.  The current sympy version is 1.4.  https://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html#mpmath

Comment: `mpmath` is not a symbolic math package, with or without `sympy`.  And wasn't so back in 0.7.6 days.

Comment: The solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759214/sympy-and-mpmath-give-typeerror-cannot-create-mpf-when-using-the-erf-functi was to use `sympy.erf` instead of `mpmath.erf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SymPy `hyper` function:

```py
In [4]: from sympy import hyper, simplify, Symbol                                                                                 

In [5]: d = Symbol('d')                                                                                                           

In [6]: f = hyper([1, 1], [1], d)                                                                                                 

In [7]: f                                                                                                                         
Out[7]: 
 ┌─  ⎛1, 1 │  ⎞
 ├─  ⎜     │ d⎟
2╵ 1 ⎝ 1   │  ⎠

In [8]: simplify(f)                                                                                                               
Out[8]: 
  1  
─────
1 - d
```