# Why nsolve is saying "cannot create mpf from -0.499923944877944."?

Tags: python, sympy, solver, symengine

I have a polynomial that I am trying to find all of the roots for numerically using nsolve. When I try to use nsolve to find the lowest root (that is the only one I really need, but I would not mind finding all of them), i get an error that says "cannot create mpf from -0.499923944877944."

I've tried using multiple different solvers. When I used SymPy's solve, it only found 5 of the roots(when there should be 6). Using solve also took a very long time, as I believe it is trying to solve it symbolically at first. I tried solveset, and that did not give the correct answer.

Below is all of my code. Everything works as it is supposed to up until the nsolve at the very bottom.

```
from symengine import *
import sympy
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy import nsolve

trial = Matrix()

r, E1, E = symbols('r, E1, E')
H11, H22, H12, H21 = symbols("H11, H22, H12, H21")
S11, S22, S12, S21 = symbols("S11, S22, S12, S21")
low = 0
high = oo

integrate = lambda *args: sympy.N(sympy.integrate(*args))

quadratic_expression = (H11-E1*S11)*(H22-E1*S22)-(H12-E1*S12)*(H21-E1*S21)
general_solution = sympify(sympy.solve(quadratic_expression, E1)[0])


def solve_quadratic(**kwargs):
    return general_solution.subs(kwargs)


def H(fun):
    return -fun.diff(r, 2)/2 - fun.diff(r)/r - fun/r


psi0 = exp(-3*r/2)
trial = trial.row_insert(0, Matrix([psi0]))
I1 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*psi0*H(psi0), (r, low, high))
I2 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*psi0**2, (r, low, high))
E0 = I1/I2
print(E0)

for x in range(5):
    f1 = psi0
    f2 = r * (H(psi0)-E0*psi0)
    Hf1 = H(f1).simplify()
    Hf2 = H(f2).simplify()

    H11 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*Hf1, (r, low, high))
    H12 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*Hf2, (r, low, high))
    H21 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2*Hf1, (r, low, high))
    H22 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2*Hf2, (r, low, high))

    S11 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1**2, (r, low, high))
    S12 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*f2, (r, low, high))
    S21 = S12
    S22 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2**2, (r, low, high))

    E0 = solve_quadratic(
            H11=H11, H22=H22, H12=H12, H21=H21,
            S11=S11, S22=S22, S12=S12, S21=S21,
        )
    print(E0)

    C = -(H11 - E0*S11)/(H12 - E0*S12)
    psi0 = (f1 + C*f2).simplify()
    trial = trial.row_insert(x+1, Matrix([[psi0]]))

# Free ICI Part

h = zeros(x+2, x+2)
HS = zeros(x+2, 1)
S = zeros(x+2, x+2)

for s in range(x+2):
    HS[s] = H(trial[s]).simplify()

for i in range(x+2):
    for j in range(x+2):
        h[i, j] = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*trial[i]*HS[j], (r, low, high))

for i in range(x+2):
    for j in range(x+2):
        S[i, j] = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*trial[i]*trial[j], (r, low, high))

m = h - E*S
eqn = m.det()

roots = nsolve(eqn, E0)

print(roots)
```

The smallest root should be greater than or equal to -0.5, but it's not even getting to the point where it gives me a root.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37759214

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9045

Comment: Robert Harvey, thank you for the links. Unfortunately, I have already viewed those, and I do not believe that they answer my question.

Comment: Do you think the traceback would help us?  Or have you studied that carefully and determined that it is of no use?

Comment: Could I run this with some replacement for `symengine` (like a plain `from sympy import *`)?

Comment: I am not sure what a traceback is, so I am not sure whether that would help or not. I do not believe you would be able to use it by making that replacement. Even if that did work, it would take way longer. My original code was all done using sympy instead of symengine, and it took way longer to run, and simply would not run for more than about 10 iterations (and that took hours). Now, except for the nsolve part, it can crunch through 10 iterations in no time.

Comment: So your code is failing for reasons other than the ones described in the posts I linked?

Comment: The reason I asked about running it is that you don't seem to be able to provide us with enough debugging information.  Unless we have encountered the same error, or something similar, it's hard to help with an error we (or you) can't reproduce.

Comment: Well I posted the whole code, so why would you not be able to reproduce those errors? Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but I am able to reproduce those errors every single time I try to run my program.

Comment: Robert Harvey, those are both giving a very similar error, but not the exact same. In both of those cases, they are not using nsolve. The answers to those problems are not applicable to my problem.

Comment: The traceback is the thing that starts "Traceback (most recent call last):" and ends "SomethingError: stuff went wrong". Post it.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I figured out what the problem is. When using nsolve, the initial guess was a symbol, when it should have been a float. Literally just wrapping that one value in float does the trick. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The initial guess when using nsolve needs to be a float, but I was putting in a symbolic number. Below is the corrected code.

```
from symengine import *
import sympy
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy import nsolve

trial = Matrix()

r, E1, E = symbols('r, E1, E')
H11, H22, H12, H21 = symbols("H11, H22, H12, H21")
S11, S22, S12, S21 = symbols("S11, S22, S12, S21")
low = 0
high = oo

integrate = lambda *args: sympy.N(sympy.integrate(*args))

quadratic_expression = (H11-E1*S11)*(H22-E1*S22)-(H12-E1*S12)*(H21-E1*S21)
general_solution = sympify(sympy.solve(quadratic_expression, E1)[0])


def solve_quadratic(**kwargs):
    return general_solution.subs(kwargs)


def H(fun):
    return -fun.diff(r, 2)/2 - fun.diff(r)/r - fun/r


psi0 = exp(-3*r/2)
trial = trial.row_insert(0, Matrix([psi0]))
I1 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*psi0*H(psi0), (r, low, high))
I2 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*psi0**2, (r, low, high))
E0 = I1/I2
print(E0)

for x in range(6):
    f1 = psi0
    f2 = r * (H(psi0)-E0*psi0)
    Hf1 = H(f1).simplify()
    Hf2 = H(f2).simplify()

    H11 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*Hf1, (r, low, high))
    H12 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*Hf2, (r, low, high))
    H21 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2*Hf1, (r, low, high))
    H22 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2*Hf2, (r, low, high))

    S11 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1**2, (r, low, high))
    S12 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f1*f2, (r, low, high))
    S21 = S12
    S22 = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*f2**2, (r, low, high))

    E0 = solve_quadratic(
            H11=H11, H22=H22, H12=H12, H21=H21,
            S11=S11, S22=S22, S12=S12, S21=S21,
        )
    print(E0)

    C = -(H11 - E0*S11)/(H12 - E0*S12)
    psi0 = (f1 + C*f2).simplify()
    trial = trial.row_insert(x+1, Matrix([[psi0]]))

# Free ICI Part

h = zeros(x+2, x+2)
HS = zeros(x+2, 1)
S = zeros(x+2, x+2)

for s in range(x+2):
    HS[s] = H(trial[s]).simplify()

for i in range(x+2):
    for j in range(x+2):
        h[i, j] = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*trial[i]*HS[j], (r, low, high))

for i in range(x+2):
    for j in range(x+2):
        S[i, j] = integrate(4*pi*(r**2)*trial[i]*trial[j], (r, low, high))

m = h - E*S
eqn = m.det()

roots = nsolve(eqn, float(E0))

print(roots)
```

If anyone knows how to speed up nsolve, I would love to hear it. I am probably just going to write my own script for the bisection method, as nsolve is taking way too long (I've been waiting hours for it to solve it when I do 11 iterations in that for loop, and that is quite ridiculous).

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider: `nsolve` will accept a solver='bisect' keyword if you know the interval in which your root lies:

```
>>> nsolve(x**2-3,x,(0.,2.),solver='bisect')
1.73205080756888
```

Also, `real_roots` may be a useful method of obtaining roots in cases like this. With x in range(6) in the code you posted, a polynomial of order 88 is obtained and solved in a short order with:

```
>>> eq=nsimplify(eqn, rational=True).as_numer_denom()[0]
>>> [i.n(3) for i in real_roots(Poly(eq,E))][:7]
[-0.836, -0.298, -0.117, -0.0821, 0.0854, 0.181, 0.399]
```